# Two Windows installed, can launch just one

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot, grub

On a laptop with two hard disks, I want to move the Windows OS from one (C:) to the other (D:). So far I could clone it on the destination drive, and looking at the directory trees of the original and the copy, they look identical.

However I can only boot the original Windows. When I try to boot the clone (pressing F12 before the boot and selecting the corresponding drive), nothing happens: I get a blank screen and then it goes back to boot from the default drive.

How can I select a specific Windows to launch during boot?

Since my intention is to install Linux on the first drive, will it be possible to start the Windows that now I cannot launch through Grub?

Comment: You do not need to install Linux and grub on the first disk. Usually you can change the order in which the computer searches the OS from the BIOS. Moreover `C:` and `D:` are logical name that exist only inside windows. Even if you put windows on your second physical drive it will probably be always `C:`.

Comment: @Hastur - I still want the first disk to boot by default. But I need to be able to boot Windows from the second disk, too.

Comment: Many times you can do directly from bios (when you boot you can use a combination of keys that depends from your computer model).